# SQL select case group by

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-function

I have a table 'LIST_USERS'.

Table Description -

```
USER_ID       NUMBER(8)
LOGIN_ID      VARCHAR2(8)
CREATE_DATE   TIMESTAMP(6)
LOGIN_DATE    TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Table data -

```
USER_ID     LOGIN_ID    CREATE_DATE     LOGIN_DATE
---------------------------------------------------
101         test1       04/24/2016      null
102         test1       04/24/2016      04/29/2016
103         test2       04/25/2016      null
104         test2       04/26/2016      null
105         test3       04/27/2016      04/28/2016
106         test3       04/27/2016      04/29/2016
107         test4       04/28/2016      04/29/2016
987         test5       04/29/2016      null
109         test5       04/29/2016      null
108         test5       04/29/2016      04/29/2016
```

Condition  - I need to fetch USER_ID, and LOGIN_ID from 'LIST_USERS' table based of max LOGIN_DATE. If LOGIN_DATE is null, I need to get the record based on max CREATE_DATE.

I need to get the below result -

```
USER_ID     LOGIN_ID
---------------------
102         test1   
104         test2
106         test3
107         test4
108         test5
```

I am using the below query. But it will give me only LOGIN_ID, and 'Login_Or_Create_Date' but I need USER_ID, and LOGIN_ID. Is there way I can get USER_ID as well as in the result shown above?

```
select LOGIN_ID,
       (case when max(LOGIN_DATE) is null then max(CREATE_DATE)
             else max(LOGIN_DATE) end) as Login_Or_Create_Date
from   LIST_USERS;
```

Comment: What happens if a user logs in twice on the same day? Which one would you want to keep?

Comment: There is a bug in the application and that has resulted in the above scenario. Basically I need to retain the latest record and clean up the other records .

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT USER_ID, LOGIN_ID
FROM (
  SELECT USER_ID, LOGIN_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOGIN_ID 
                            ORDER BY COALESCE(LOGIN_DATE, CREATE_DATE) DESC) AS rn
FROM LIST_USERS) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I have tweaked the data in the table. Will it work with the above query?

Comment: That's the query that I ended up with, as well.

Comment: @user2893856 I cannot imagine what your actual data set looks like. you can try it out and see what result the query produces.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [`keep dense_rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm):

```
select min(user_id) keep (dense_rank last order by coalesce(login_date, create_date))
    as user_id,
  login_id
from list_users
group by login_id
order by user_id;
```

The [`last`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm) keeps the record with the latest login/create date; the `coalesce()` takes the login date first and falls back to the create date if that is null (or you could use `nvl()` instead of course). You could also do `first` and order by `desc` - the result is the same (if there are no nulls anyway, and it looks like there shouldn't be), but `last` feels more intuitive when you want the latest date I think.
Demo using your data in a CTE:

```
with list_users(user_id, login_id, create_date, login_date) as (
  select 101, 'test1', date '2016-04-24', null from dual
  union all select 102, 'test1', date '2016-04-24', date '2016-04-29' from dual
  union all select 103, 'test2', date '2016-04-25', null from dual
  union all select 104, 'test2', date '2016-04-26', null from dual
  union all select 105, 'test3', date '2016-04-27', date '2016-04-28' from dual
  union all select 106, 'test3', date '2016-04-27', date '2016-04-29' from dual
  union all select 107, 'test4', date '2016-04-28', date '2016-04-29' from dual
)
select min(user_id) keep (dense_rank last order by coalesce(login_date, create_date))
    as user_id,
  login_id
from list_users
group by login_id
order by user_id;

   USER_ID LOGIN
---------- -----
       102 test1
       104 test2
       106 test3
       107 test4
```

And with your modified data:

```
with list_users(user_id, login_id, create_date, login_date) as (
  select 101, 'test1', date '2016-04-24', null from dual
  union all select 102, 'test1', date '2016-04-24', date '2016-04-29' from dual
  union all select 103, 'test2', date '2016-04-25', null from dual
  union all select 104, 'test2', date '2016-04-26', null from dual
  union all select 105, 'test3', date '2016-04-27', date '2016-04-28' from dual
  union all select 106, 'test3', date '2016-04-27', date '2016-04-29' from dual
  union all select 107, 'test4', date '2016-04-28', date '2016-04-29' from dual
  union all select 987, 'test5', date '2016-04-29', null from dual
  union all select 109, 'test5', date '2016-04-29', null from dual
  union all select 108, 'test5', date '2016-04-29', date '2016-04-29' from dual
)
select min(user_id) keep (dense_rank last order by coalesce(login_date, create_date))
    as user_id,
  login_id
from list_users
group by login_id
order by user_id;

   USER_ID LOGIN
---------- -----
       102 test1
       104 test2
       106 test3
       107 test4
       108 test5
```

Comment: `Keep` is a new one for me

Comment: I have tweaked the data in the table. Will it work with the above query?

Comment: @user2893856 - yes; wouldn't it have been easier to just try it yourself?